# Paste returns of a javascript function into Excel (dictionary "attack")

Tags: javascript, excel, dictionary

I have a Website that use a javascript function to validate a 5 characters text.

The HTML code is like this:

```
<p class="form-control-static ret">
            Input your Text:
            <input type="text" name="text_input" id="text_input" maxlength="5" value="">
            <button class="validate-button" id="btn">Check!</button>
          </p> 

<script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btn").click(function(e){ 
                  e.preventDefault();
                  location.href = "https://www.url_here?sc=" + $('#text_input').val();
                });
              });
              </script>
```

The 5 characters text goes directly in the URL.

Examples:

https://www.url_here?sc=ABCDE

https://www.url_here?sc=ATTEF

Is is possible to make a Macro on Excel that try all URls with the given options and paste in a Spread sheet the texts that returned True?

Or, does it have an easiest way to do that?

All i need is an automatically dictionary "attack".

Comment: This is a great way to accidentally knock your server down.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve? If this for research purposes only, that's fine, but you cannot validate user input with scripting or anything handled on the client-side with the goal of preventing an attack. That all has to be done on the server. Client validation is for user experience and for preventing common validation errors, but it will not protect from any kind of attack.

Comment: @ssube I know that depends on the number of request i can slow down or knock down the server. But, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Jason It for research purposes! The website this way is too vulnerable in this kind of attack

Comment: @xxnsra I was pretty sure that was the case, but I feel like I have the duty to ask anyway just in case :) I like your idea, but unfortunately don't have any suggestions, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need a remote controllable application to make http requests. I'd recommend the command line tool "wget".

Then write a VBA-script that reads the lines in excel and calls "wget" each time.

If you want more options, you could have a look to the complex and sophisticated tool "JMeter".

Answer (score 0):

26^5 = 11881376 (only counting CAPITAL LETTERS),  so your site would have to address this many service calls if you want to do it this way.

If you want to test this, I would refactor the server side code, separate the validation function, and call it internally with a key generator.

Comment: It depends on the texts in the excel sheet. If the excel sheets contains only 100 texts, then doing 100 requests should not be an issue.